# What is the etymology of the question ending `ㄴ가`/`는가`/`ㄹ가(ㄹ까)`?

Tags: verb-endings, etymology, sentence-endings

Since for the ending `ㄴ가`/`는가`/`ㄹ가(ㄹ까)`, there is an obligatorily incorporated "relativiser-looking" particle (`ㄴ`/`는`/`ㄹ`), I am wondering whether this expression has evolved from a "relative clause-dependent noun" structure. Moreover, I have seen expressions such as `있을까를 생각한다`, suggesting there is something "nominal" about this ending as it can be attached to by an overt case marker.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, (ㄴ/는)가 does not have special etymological connection to relative clause construction (-ㄹ까 and -ㄴ/는가 are different question endings). They are just question endings that are a little more formal and objective sounding (and thus can create a noun clause more easily) than the most colloquial question endings like -아/어?

In Korean, relative clauses are very easily created with the -ㄴ/는 verb endings.  Although ㄴ/는 appear in (ㄴ/는)가, it can't be considered to be related to a relative clause since 가 is never used as a noun.

Also note that we don't even use the term "relative clause" much because plain adjectives and relative clauses, unlike English, take the same form.  **좋은** 직업 ("good job" - plain adj), and **내가 가진** 직업 ("the job that I have" - rel. clause) have the same connective form of -(으)ㄴ and come before the noun (the difference is just additional words in front), so there is no need for a special category like "relative clause".  Both are just adjective forms - one a single word and the other a clause.  Often times even this distinction may be blurred.

There are many question ending forms with a varying degree in their abilities  to create a clause.  Here are a few common ones.

- -(느)냐? = likely the "standard", most frequently used question ending in a clause.
  언제 가느냐? (direct question like this is not so common nowadays)
  언제 가느냐(고) 물었다 (noun (or adverb?) clause - very common)
  언제 가느냐는 질문 (adjective clause - very common)
- -아/어? = colloquial. Usually asks something specific about the person.
  너 언제 가? (direct question - very common)
  This form is not used as a clause much - 냐? handles it as shown above.
- -ㄴ/느/ㄹ가? = more formal and suitable for non-personal questions.
  평화의 시대는 언제 올 것인가? = literary and directed to people at large.
  평화의 시대는 언제 오느냐는 물음 = simplest and most natural sounding  adjective clause form.
  '평화의 시대는 언제 오는가'라는 물음 = direct quoting which is always possible.
  평화의 시대는 언제 오는가, 라는 물음 = literary, and the connection is not as natural as 오느냐는.
- -ㄹ까? = colloquial, (partially) self-directed question ending.
  You can use it in a noun clause but it is not the most preferred way.
  E.g. 왜 실패했는지(를)/실패했는가(를) 생각해 보았다 sound more proper than 왜 실패했을까(를) 생각해 보았다.

Comment: This I think should be accepted as the answer